# Using Extension on User does not Return Value for User

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have a standard page. Just following the basic implementation in the Apex Docs, but instead of Account I'm using User. However, the extension is not bringing back any values from the methods in the extension. Any help would be great!

#### VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="User" extensions="HB_BS_UserController" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:pageMessages/>
        <!-- <h1>Edit User {!$User.FirstName}</h1> -->
        <p>{!userNameMessage}</p>
        <apex:form>
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField label="The Name" value="{!User.FirstName }"/>
                <apex:inputField label="LastName" value="{!User.LastName }"/>
               
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            
        </apex:form> 



</apex:page>
```

### Controller

```
public with sharing class HB_BS_UserController {
    public User user {get;set;} 
    public HB_BS_UserController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.user = (User)stdController.getRecord();
        System.debug(this.user.Id); // returns null 
    }

    public String getUserNameMessage(){
        return 'This is the userName = ' + this.user.FirstName; // value here is null. 
    }
}
```

Comment: when you invoked the page, did you include a `?id=theUserId` in the URL string?

Comment: No, but I'm able to output the UserId from the standard controller using {!$User.Id}.

Comment: `{!$User}` and `{!User}`  are two different things - the former is the running user; the latter is the target object of the standard controller

Comment: Are you saying that `{!$User}` has nothing to do with the StandardController being there?

Comment: Either way, I'm not sure that really matters given the code example.

Comment: Please use [edit] and show the URL that invokes the page

Comment: This standard controller will show that users detail whose id value is present in the URL. {!$User} shows info of current logged un user.

Comment: @cropredy started thread on the first answer. You may have thoughts on my comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi thinker you have to pass userId in url

/apex/VFPAGE?id=userId

then it will start showing expected result

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think this gets at the heart of the question. Does the standard ApexController require there to be an ID in the URL. If I don't want to expose the ID in the URL, is there a way to get the id from a StandardController without putting it in the URL?

Comment: @thinker no.  You could use a custom controller and pass in id via cookies if you want to avoid exposing ID in url.  But why is this a requirement?

Comment: from where you are calling this apex page ?

Comment: We are exposing in an iframe, and i want to avoid using the url if I can help it. Would like to keep everything in the controller. Was thinking I could use STandardController and then extend it, but I think Custom Controller will be the better option.

Comment: @cropredy if you throw your answer here into the Anwers. I will give it the best answer. Thank you for your clarification and help.

Comment: then you can create custom controller and use post message to send value to you vf page after that remote action to call your controller method .Here i am attaching salesforce docs for your reference https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm